# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: Phone

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, constraints

Since i used the @phone annotation as validator it rising 
some exception as illegal argument.Any clues? How to have our own annotation in this im using @Ajay for phone validating but its not working.Please help me to resolve this problem and send me code for having customize validation. or please share some links to understand about custom validation.

This is my model class:

```
            package com.dineshonjava.bean;


            import com.dineshonjava.validator.Ajay;
           @Entity
            @Table(name="employees")
            @SecondaryTable(name="employeedetails")
            public class EmployeeBean {
            @Ajay
            private String phone;


            public String getPhone() {
                return phone;
            }
            public void setPhone(String phone) {
                this.phone = phone;
            }

            }
```

This is my customized annotation class.This code i got it from internet but its showing error when implementing in my project.i dono how to have customize validation in my project.
Ajay Annotation:

```
            package com.dineshonjava.validator;
             import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
            import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
            import java.lang.annotation.Target;
            import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
            import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
           import javax.validation.Constraint;
            import javax.validation.Payload;
            @Documented
            @Constraint(validatedBy = AjayValidator.class)
            @Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
            @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
            public @interface Ajay {
                 String message() default "{Phone}";

                Class<?>[] groups() default {};

                Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

            }
```

This is my Validator class here i did coding for validating my phone number here i did customized validation for that @Ajay annotation i did validation in this validator class.
Ajay Validator:

```
            package com.dineshonjava.validator;

            import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
            import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

            public class AjayValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Ajay, String> {

                    @Override
                    public void initialize(Ajay ajay) { 

                    }
                  @Override
            public boolean isValid(String phone, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
                if(phone == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                return phone.matches("[0-9()-/.]*");
            }

            }
```

error while running my coding:

```
Nov 20, 2017 12:37:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\ecllipse\eclipse;;.
Nov 20, 2017 12:37:58 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring3HibernateApp' did not find a matching property.
Nov 20, 2017 12:37:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 20, 2017 12:37:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 20, 2017 12:37:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 438 ms
Nov 20, 2017 12:37:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 20, 2017 12:37:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Nov 20, 2017 12:38:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'sdnext'
Nov 20, 2017 12:38:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 20, 2017 12:38:02 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 20, 2017 12:38:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3897 ms
Nov 20, 2017 12:38:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Phone"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceSupport.createMessageFormat(MessageSourceSupport.java:115)
    at org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceSupport.formatMessage(MessageSourceSupport.java:99)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.renderDefaultMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getMessage(RequestContext.java:559)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.initErrorMessages(BindStatus.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.getErrorMessages(BindStatus.java:273)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag.exposeAttributes(ErrorsTag.java:172)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.writeTagContent(AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.addEmployee_jsp._jspService(addEmployee_jsp.java:393)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Nov 20, 2017 12:38:04 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [sdnext] in context with path [/sdnext] threw exception [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't parse argument number: Phone] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Phone"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.makeFormat(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.applyPattern(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceSupport.createMessageFormat(MessageSourceSupport.java:115)
    at org.springframework.context.support.MessageSourceSupport.formatMessage(MessageSourceSupport.java:99)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.renderDefaultMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getMessage(RequestContext.java:559)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.initErrorMessages(BindStatus.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.getErrorMessages(BindStatus.java:273)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.ErrorsTag.exposeAttributes(ErrorsTag.java:172)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.writeTagContent(AbstractHtmlElementBodyTag.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.addEmployee_jsp._jspService(addEmployee_jsp.java:393)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution to your problem is right in your question:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Phone"
```

You try to parse the String "Phone" as a number. Which, of course, is not possible, as it does not contain any numbers, but only characters.

Comment: where can i change that bro can u please tell me in detail

Comment: The lines below the `NumberFormatException` state, that the parsing of the String is coming from the `MessageFormat` class. In Validators, the message is this `String message() default "{Phone}";` So it seems that your code is trying to parse the default message `{Phone}` as an Integer. Try some different approaches with the default message. You can use plain text or message bundle keys. Start with plain text: `String message() default "Phone Validator Message";` and see if this works. If yes, `{Phone}` seems to trigger something different then plain text ;-)

Comment: Got the solution. Thanks for your help bro.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LCAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolverBean() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource=new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("external");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean localValidatorFactoryBean=new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        localValidatorFactoryBean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return localValidatorFactoryBean;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        registry.addFormatter(new PhoneNumberFormatter());
    }
    @Override
    public Validator getValidator() {
        return validator();
    }

}
```

You have to define a custom validator and tell spring to use that specific file.

Here I have defined a `messageSource()` which returns a `MessageSource` object to locate the properties file (which in my case is "external.properties").

After this we have to register this `messageSource()` method using `LocalValidatorFactoryBean` class and finally register validator method by overriding the `getValidator` method of `WebMvcConfigurer` interface, which we implemented in our class.

For complete reference watch this video from 1:55:00
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNpJGvFR5uI&list=PL3NrzZBjk6m_2jw8sC0BkEwSPFHxgQDWr&index=10